# c# Print from the printer using usb Cable, without using ip address or shared printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm looking for how to print from the printer without using an IP address or sharing the printer.

i am using the code below and i used the ip address \127.0.0.1\Citizen_CL-S700 for the printer but now i need to print without share the printer or use usb cable

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(PrintFolder + @"\MEFU_" + Cmb_Serial_Print.Text + ".prn", true);
                        writer.Write(content);
                        writer.Close();

                        File.Copy(PrintFolder + @"\MEFU_" + Cmb_Serial_Print.Text + ".prn",\\127.0.0.1\Citizen_CL-S700);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage:

```
 using RawPrint;

    // Create an instance of the Printer
    IPrinter printer = new Printer();

    // Print the file
    printer.PrintRawFile(PrinterName, Filepath, Filename);
```

Installation:

To install Raw Print, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package RawPrint
```